# Find Deadlock in Graph

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-algorithm

In a multithreaded environment, it's possible that different processes will need to use the same resource. A *wait-for* graph represents the different processes as nodes in a directed graph, where an edge from node `i` to node `j` means that the node `j` is using a resource that node `i` needs to use (and cannot use until node `j` releases it).

We are interested in whether or not this digraph has any cycles in it. If it does, it is possible for the system to get into a state where no process can complete.

We will represent the processes by integers `0`, ...., `n - 1`. We represent the edges using a two-dimensional list `connections`. If `j` is in the list `connections[i]`, then there is a directed edge from process `i` to process `j`.

Write a function that returns `True` if `connections` describes a graph with a directed cycle, or `False` otherwise.

Example

- For `connections = [[1], [2], [3, 4], [4], [0]]`, the output should be`findDeadlock(connections) = true`.

This graph contains a cycle.

- For `connections = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], []]`, the output should be`findDeadlock(connections) = false`.

Here is a task.

Here is my implementation:

```
class Node {
      constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
      }
    }
    class LinkedList {
      constructor() {
        this.head = null;
      }
      insertAtHead(data) {
        let temp = new Node(data);
        temp.next = this.head;
        this.head = temp;
        return this;
      }
      getHead() {
        return this.head;
      }
    }
    class Graph {
      constructor(vertices) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.list = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
          let temp = new LinkedList();
          this.list.push(temp);
        }
      }
      addEdge(source, destination) {
        if (source < this.vertices && destination < this.vertices) {
          this.list[source].insertAtHead(destination);
        }
        return this;
      }
    }
    
    const Colors = {
      WHITE: "white",
      GRAY: "gray",
      BLACK: "black",
    };
    
    Object.freeze(Colors);
    
    const  isDeadlocked = (g) => {
      let color = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < g.vertices; i++) {
        color[i] = Colors.WHITE;
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < g.vertices; i++) {
        if (color[i] == Colors.WHITE) {
          if (detectCycle(g, i, color)) {
              console.log(true)
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
       console.log(false);
      return false;
    }
    const detectCycle = (g, currentVertex, color) => {
      color[currentVertex] = Colors.GRAY;
      let neighbor;
      let nextNode = g.list[currentVertex].getHead();
      while (nextNode !== null) {
        neighbor = nextNode.data;
        if (color[neighbor] == Colors.GRAY) {
          return true;
        }
        if (color[neighbor] == Colors.WHITE && detectCycle(g, neighbor, color)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      color[currentVertex] = Colors.BLACK;
      return false;
    }
    
    const findDeadlock = (input) => {
        const g = new Graph(input.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
               g.addEdge(i, input[i][j]);
            }
        }
        isDeadlocked(g);
    }
    const connections = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], []];
    findDeadlock(connections);
```

My code fails the second test. Cannot find the reason why. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least the following two issues:

(1) The input is not correctly translated into edges. The following code:

```
g.addEdge(i, j);
```

should be:

```
g.addEdge(i, input[i][j]);
```

(2) The loop variable in `detectCycle` is not updated for the next iteration. Just before the end of the loop, you should include:

```
nextNode = nextNode.next;
```

**General remark:** Although your `LinkedList` implementation is fine, it is rarely useful to really implement such a structure in JavaScript. You can use a simple array, or a `Set` if you want.